# Formatting git-log using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, git-log

I want to format git-log match in a convenient way.
The output of git-log command is given:

```
commit 11ae9c97409fb349e2bfa50ed65bd23ec6dbca70
Author: Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 11 19:51:30 2012 +0200

    updated VERSION for 2.0.16

commit 6e14d67cb23439d6700f494e29e809811edeeade
Author: Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 11 19:50:55 2012 +0200

    update CONTRIBUTORS for 2.0.16

commit 0341492ed566fca8df556573b9664f691c5dff3d
Author: Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 11 19:48:12 2012 +0200

    updated CHANGELOG for 2.0.16

commit b18f6f557b5db1e2e6d2c2c0494e0564b91f438d
Author: Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jul 10 15:28:02 2012 +0200

    [Console] fixed wrong phpdoc (closes #4394)
```

I want to format as given below:

```
Fabien Potencier, Wed Jul 11 19:51:30 2012 +0200

    updated VERSION for 2.0.16

Fabien Potencier, Wed Jul 11 19:50:55 2012 +0200

    update CONTRIBUTORS for 2.0.16

Fabien Potencier, Wed Jul 11 19:48:12 2012 +0200

    updated CHANGELOG for 2.0.16

Fabien Potencier, Tue Jul 10 15:28:02 2012 +0200

    [Console] fixed wrong phpdoc (closes #4394)
```

for that I wrote a PHP script  as given below.

```
<?php

$r = shell_exec('git log');

$p = '/commit (.{2})(.{4})(.{6})/';// THIS SHOULD CHANGE!

preg_match_all($p, $r, $match);

unset($match[0]);

$output = array();

foreach($match as $k1=> $v1)

    foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2)

          @$output[$k2] .= $v2 . ($k1==1 ? ',' : PHP_EOL);

echo implode('', $output);
```

I don't have any idea about the pattern I should be used here. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
/Author:\s*(?<name>.+)\s+Date:\s*(?<date>.+)\s+(?<message>(?:(?!commit .{40}).)+)/i
```

Three backreferences set, one for each set of data you want.

Print the `$match`-array if you need help understanding the saved data.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/cA0lD3

Comment: can you explain "(?:(?!commit .{40}).)" ?

Comment: Absolutely. It's a very useful construct you should learn. You forgot the crucial part though - the quantifier. Without it its useless. So basically what this does is try to match a character, and at every position it matches a character, it performs a negative lookahead to make sure the specified string was not found. Then it continues up until it does. That's it. If you want to learn more, check out http://regex101.com/quiz/ (just a quick registration). Task 15 in that quiz handles this subject.